# Fade-in and fade-out in pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, animation

I decided to build my own fade-in fade-out function, since that is all I need on my page.

Please comment on things I can make better.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
        <div>
        <span id="fade_in">Fade In</span> | 
        <span id="fade_out">Fade Out</span></div>
        <div id="fading_div" style="display:none;height:100px;background:#f00">Fading Box</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
// global varibles
var done = true,
    fading_div = document.getElementById('fading_div'),
    fade_in_button = document.getElementById('fade_in'),
    fade_out_button = document.getElementById('fade_out');

function function_opacity(opacity_value, fade_in_or_fade_out) { // fade_in_or_out - 0 = fade in, 1 = fade out
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity_value / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity_value + ')';
    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'in' && opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'in' && opacity_value == 100) {
        done = true;
    }
    if (fade_in_or_fade_out == 'out' && opacity_value == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'none';
        done = true;
    }
}

// fade in button
fade_in_button.onclick = function () {
    if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '1') {
        done = false;
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
            setTimeout("function_opacity(" + i + ",'in')", i * 5);
        }
    }
};

// fade out button
fade_out_button.onclick = function () {
    if (done && fading_div.style.opacity !== '0') {
        done = false;
        for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
            setTimeout("function_opacity(" + i + ",'out')", (i - 100) * -1 * 5);
        }
    }
};
alert (test);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could skip all of this and let css transitions do the work for you. http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/transitions/

Comment: GGG, maybe it's a good idea. People will be updating there browsers more often in 2012.

Comment: Yeah, I think it's fine for something like a fade (progressive enhancement). People who's browsers don't support it won't see the fade, but the thing will still appear/disappear, so they're just missing out on a visual effect, and you get to save 50 or 60 lines of javascript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just some generic notes about the JavaScript code: I'd extract out a `setOpacity` function and create a `fadeOut` and a `fadeIn` function too.

```
function setOpacity(opacity) {
    fading_div.style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    fading_div.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
}

function fadeOut(opacity) {
    setOpacity(opacity);
    if (opacity == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'none';
        done = true;
    }
}

function fadeIn(opacity) {
    setOpacity(opacity);
    if (opacity == 1) {
        fading_div.style.display = 'block';
    }
    if (opacity == 100) {
        done = true;
    }
}

...
setTimeout("fadeIn(" + i + ")", i * 5);
...
```

It eliminates the `in` and `out` magic constants and lots of conditions which checks their values.

Using variable name suffixes like `opacity_value` looks a little bit redundant (since variables stores values), so I've renamed them. The same is true for the `function_opacity` function.

I've changed the second for loop too to use fewer arithmetic operations, I think the following is easier to read:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
    setTimeout("fadeOut(" + (100 - i) + ")", i * 5);
}
```

Comment: Please don't pass strings to `setTimeout`!  It `eval`s them.  Pass a function.  `setTimeout((function(x){ return function(){ fadeOut(100-x); }; })(i), i * 5);`  It's in a closure because `i` changes in the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks, @Rocket! Could you give me an example or link with some explanation why is it better? I'm not a JavaScript guru. (Maybe you want to write it as an answer since in the question there is the same string passing, and we will be able to upvote it.)

Answer (score 4):

This is just an extension to @palacsint's answer.  You shouldn't pass strings to `setTimeout`, it uses `eval`, which is inefficient and insecure.  You should pass a function.

Problem is, in the `for` loop `i` changes, so you'll have to use a closure.

Don't do this:

```
for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
   setTimeout("function_opacity(" + i + ",'out')", (i - 100) * -1 * 5);
}
```

Instead do:

```
for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
   setTimeout((function(x){
      return function(){
         function_opacity(x, 'out')
      };
   })(i), (i - 100) * -1 * 5);
}
```

This may look a little messy.  I suggest declaring a function that returns a function separately.

```
function call_opacity(i, d){
    return function(){
      function_opacity(i, d);
    };
}
```

Then do:

```
for (var i = 100; i >= 1; i--) {
   setTimeout(call_opacity(i, 'out'), (i - 100) * -1 * 5);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rocket! Here is a link on the subject to back up your answer. Thanks for shring! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232574/is-it-bad-practice-to-pass-a-string-to-settimeout-if-yes-why